# How to make a component stick to corners and not stay in the same position if the form is resized in java?

Tags: java

I have designed a code for `JTextPane`, what I want to do is put that `JTextPane` in the bottom right corner, it is is fine as long as the form isn't resized (I want the form to be resizeable) but when it is resized the `JTextPane` does not move along. How can I make it stick to that right corner and move about if the form has been resized, I do not need it to cover the full contentPane. here is my code for the `JTextPane`

```
JTextPane txtpnHello = new JTextPane();
txtpnHello.setText("Hello");
txtpnHello.setEnabled(false);
contentPane.add(txtpnHello);
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your `contentPane`? `JDialog`, `JPanel`, `JFrame`??? And are you using a [Layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)?

Comment: What [`Layout Manager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) are you using?

Comment: You can take a look at this related [question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905731/how-to-put-component-in-bottom-right-corner-with-gridbaglayout?rq=1)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make jLabels stay attached to the corners of a window form, despite resizing the form in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21463352/how-to-make-jlabels-stay-attached-to-the-corners-of-a-window-form-despite-resiz)

Comment: Ask questions to to those who answered your previous exact question (a couple hours ago) if you don't understand something. Don't ask the exact question again. You previous question probably lacked clarity or effort on your part to get a precise answer, just as this question does. You could always edit your question with some updated information or more questions, if all you wanted was a bump.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SpringLayout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html), perhaps like this -

```
SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(layout); // <-- Add the layout manager.
JTextPane txtpnHello = new JTextPane();
// The "Spring" for right
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, txtpnHello, 5,
        SpringLayout.EAST, contentPane);
// The "spring" for the bottom.
layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, txtpnHello, 5, 
        SpringLayout.SOUTH, contentPane);
txtpnHello.setText("Hello");
txtpnHello.setEnabled(false);
contentPane.add(txtpnHello);
```